# entity framework keeps generating 2 separate class files which leads to conflicting names

Tags: vb.net, winforms, entity-framework, visual-studio-2012

i'm using vs 2012- ef 5 working with model first approach, and the ef keeps on creating tow separate class files for each entity, one is as sub item under the model.tt file, and the other is within the model.designer.vb file.
i'v tried everything, and searched the web, but found nothing, even after entering the error code and desc. in msdn.
i'v also tried to remove the .tt file, but that lead to an exception and i got a message that "visual studio cannot locate the file ...tt"
i will really appreciate help, because i can't go on with my app.

Comment: Did you manually add a code generation item to the context?

Comment: no. i'v only added a ef model to the project